# Remove extra space between two IconButton in ROw

Tags: flutter, widget, flutter-layout, flutter-widget

I want to remove some extra space between two IconButton in Row widget 
I tried much more but still not able to remove space between widgets

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text("Home",
          style: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            fontSize: 15,
            color: Colors.black
          )
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.edit,
                color: Colors.black,
                size: 20,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                IntelUtility.navigateToScreen(
                  context, EditHomeAddressScreen()
                );
              },
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.delete,
                color: Colors.black,
                size: 20,
              ),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
),
```

Please help to solving this issue i am in trouble :(

[image: pic]

Comment: i dont think its extra space between two IconButtons - basically both icons have some padding so you have to remove that "padding" - to make sure run your app from the terminal `flutter run` and press `p` key

Comment: there is no space actually according to material concept space is needed for touch buttons so as to user not get it difficult to touch the required button. Try touching ion you will see hover effect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using IconButton,
you can use CupertinoButton like this :

```
CupertinoButton(
  minSize: double.minPositive,
  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
  child: Icon(
    Icons.delete,
    color: Color.black,
    size: 20
  ),
  onPressed: () {},
)
```

Comment: Thanks buddy  Great :)

Answer (score 1):

Add param `padding: EdgeInsets.all(0)` to IconButton.

```
IconButton(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.delete,
            color: Colors.black,
            size: 20,
          ),
          onPressed: () {},
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is BoxConstraints

```
Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              constraints: BoxConstraints.tight(Size.fromWidth(30)),
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.edit,
                color: Colors.black,
                size: 20,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                IntelUtility.navigateToScreen(
                  context, EditHomeAddressScreen()
                );
              },
            ),
            IconButton(
              constraints: BoxConstraints.tight(Size.fromWidth(30)),
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.delete,
                color: Colors.black,
                size: 20,
              ),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

You can change `constraints: BoxConstraints.tight(Size.fromWidth(30)),` whatever you want

Comment: Bro how can i use this? its shows me error undefine contrains!!!

Comment: constraint is in beta right now, I tought that stable and master contains constraints too